# Was The Fallen ever mentioned or appeared in any of the other Transformers canons?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-revenge-of-the-fallen

Was The Fallen ever mentioned or appeared in any of the other *Transformers* canons or was he made entirely up for the film *Transformers 2: Revenge of The Fallen*?

Looking for instances of him in any of the cartoon canons.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_(Transformers)#Character_history

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He was first created for the [*Transformers: War Within: The Dark Ages*](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_War_Within:_The_Dark_Ages) comic book mini-series published by Dreamwave, a story line that was never concluded due to Dreamwave going bankrupt.

[image: The Fallen]

In the Aligned continuity (*War for Cybertron*, *Fall of Cybertron* and *Transformes: Prime*), the Fallen was a name given to Megatronus, one of the Thirteen Primes and the first Decepticon.

Has has made no cartoon or animated appearances so far.

Comment: He made an appearance by now in one of the animated series as far as I'm aware. (The sequel to the "Prime" series).

Comment: He also appears in Transformers: Robots In Disguise.